# iOS Facebook SDK 3.1 how to login within apps and keep credentials?

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, authentication, sdk

Is it possible to use the Facebook iOS SDK to authenticate within an app (not go to Safari or Facebook app), and also keep those authentication credentials for the next launch of the app?

When I try to use the demo app in the simulator, it always goes to safari to authenticate, which seems a bit crappy. And then, after I authenticate I couldn't redirect back to my app.

Is there a way, to just present the user with just an email field and a password field and then keep that info.. within the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You always have to use the Facebook app for SSO in best case or Safari in worst case to login. Of course you could also use `SLComposeViewController` since iOS6 which brings the best user experience.

The only way I can imagine to do what you want is by hacking a UIWebView to load the facebook login page without showing it to the user and inject the credentials if that is possible at all!? I guess that would be pretty tricky and take quite an effort to do. Rather stick to the common way of doing it.

Take a look at the [Facebook SDK docs](https://developers.facebook.com/mobile/) or into open source projects like [BMSocialShare](https://github.com/blockhaus/BMSocialShare).

Comment: Are you 100% sure that we are not able to fetch the built-in credentials from the device/simulator? @vinzenzweber

Comment: Looking at the date of my comment, this could have changed within the last two years.

Comment: it changed, I used parse to do the oauth